# Ubuntu 18.04 asking for password to restart system

Tags: authentication

So I have may problems with Ubuntu 18.04, dummy Output, which I tried to solve using the many guides that I found on the internet, none of them worked and now if I try to restart the computer it is asking my password because it says that there is an app that asked to inhibit it, so my question is, what happens if I just reboot it, am I going to ruin my computer?? Sorry if the question seems dumb, but I'm a noob in this regard

Comment: Question isn't dumb but lacks fundamental details like which app is being mentioned. But troubleshooting a system that will become unsupported in less than one year is. Do your backups and install fresh Ubuntu 22.04, supported until 2027.

Comment: You mention rebooting it but didn't say specifically how.  If you do decide you need t reboot it; I'd avoid using power-button etc. but would consider a SysRq command direct to kernel to be *generally* safe if you flushed buffers etc (ie. REISUB) so the how you reboot may impact the result.  (*if you don't know what I'm talking about; search "magic sysrq" on a device and you'll see a wikipedia page.. the SysRq commands allow you to command the linux kernel directly regardless of OS/GUI even if they aren't responding*)